# Finding Times within a Certain Span

Tags: c#, winforms, time, datagridview

Here is my scenario: When I click an item from datagridview I want to check to see if the job such as fixing a computer is not going to happen at the same time as another event on my schedule. If one event is at 1pm on 6/14/20 I don't want to allow the user to be able to select another job that overlaps with that one. I actually want a minimum of an hour between events. Where do I start with this?

I have a datagridview that gets data from a Mysql table called jobs. It displays all of the details of the job (date, time, type of event, etc.). When I click on an item from the table it stores the data in string variables and opens another window to confirm the user's selection. For example JobType will get stored in a string called type, date will get stored in a string date, time will get stored in a string time. I want the check to occur before the confirmation window pops up.

This is a windows forms app in C#

Here is my code that i tried:

```
  //convert date time that is selected from datagridview
                    DateTime dtselected = DateTime.Parse(date + " " + time);
                    //convert date time of each job
                    DateTime dtstored = DateTime.Parse(job.JobDateTime);

                    //subtract values
                    TimeSpan value1 = dtselected.Subtract(dtstored);
                    TimeSpan value2 = dtstored.Subtract(dtselected);
                    //set minimum difference between the two times to be 1 hour and 5 minutes
                    TimeSpan difference = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 5, 0, 0);
                    //check if two times overlap
                    if(value1 <= difference || value2 <= difference)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Job times too close");
                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: _”When I click an item from datagridview I want to check to see if the event is not going to interfere with another._” … then write some code that checks for these conflicting events. It is unclear how these events are stored or how the user selects an event. There are too many unknowns to give a valid answer. … _”Where do I start with this?”_ I suggest writing some code that checks all the currently selected events to see if the newly selected event conflicts with any of the existing events. “How” you do this will depend on how the events are stored/displayed. This question needs clarity.

Comment: I tried to clarify it. Let me know if you need anymore details

Comment: The question is still not clear. If you  _” have a datagridview that gets data from a Mysql table called jobs. It displays all of the details of the job (date, time, type of event, etc.)”_ AND you … _”want the check to occur before the confirmation window pops up”_… then what is preventing the code from looping through the existing “jobs” and check for these date and time conflicts? This sounds fairly straight forward however, it is unclear “what” the problem is. Are the results incorrect or do you get an error? Without some code, it is difficult to see what is not working as expected.

Comment: I added the code that I tried. When I run the code every job is too close together

Comment: The posted code is awkward in a sense that the `if` statement is ALWAYS going to produce a `true` value. When the code obtains `value1` and `value2` … it is “guaranteed” that one of the values will be a NEGATIVE number unless BOTH values are the same. Given that one of the values (`value1` or `value2`) will be a “negative” number AND the variable `difference` is a “positive” number, then it will always return true with `value1` or `value2` being less than the positive value `difference`.

Comment: Given this, I am betting that taking the absolute value would make this work. In addition, since the two values `value1` and `value2` will only differ in the sign, and since we only want the “positive” value… then you only need one (1) value.   Example change the `if` statement to: `if (value1.Duration() <= difference) {…}`

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the issue